# Using Sencha Touch with Phonegap without Xcode

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch

I have been developing application using Sencha Touch 2.
I want to record a voice, so I searched how to achieve this with HTML5 but as I found it is not possible (on mobile devices).

And i decided to use Phonegap. But all Phonegap+sencha touch integration examples that i found are always ios or android specific. Isnt there a way to write the code with javascript as I did with sencha (and possibly with phonegap) and then deploy packages that suits ios or android?

If it is only for the test purposes, i can test them with ios's web browser to see if i am able to record audio or not, am i right or am i missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using PhoneGap, yes. PhoneGap/Cordova contains APIs for things like recording audio that you can access through JavaScript: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media

The easiest way to build your apps (without setting up a local XCODE or Eclipse/Android SDK environment) is using Adobes cloud building platform http://build.phonegap.com/

You can however not run this just through a browser (well, there may be workarounds but it shouldn't be) as you need to access device features and need to use those permissions (RECORD_AUDIO etc.). PhoneGap Build makes it easy to try it on your device though.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are trying to implement is device dependent, and sencha is just javascript. Phonegap provides options to add the device related features to the hybrid application. So it is necessary. Or else you need to find way to call iOS api from javascript.